# merge object with another that uses mirror modifier

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I want to merge 2 objects using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> but one of them has a mirror modifier, and I don't want it for the other object. How can I do that?[image]

Comment: Apply the mirror modifier before merging them together.

Comment: You want to merge 2 *faces* ? Or to *join* 2 objects (that's what is done with `Ctrl`+`J`) ?